# Format part of text in Custom Cell (iPhone-SDK)

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsstring

Is it possible to format only a part of the text of a string?

User searches, and if the search entry is found in the array, it will highlight that particular part of the text only.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Not in a standard `UILabel`, it isn't. You could draw the cell's contents yourself in its `-drawRect:` method, and draw the string in parts with different attributes. Or you could use one of the several third-party label classes out there that allow this. (For example, Three20's `TTStyledLabel`.)